# Ler um "value" dentro de um "<select></select>"

Tags: javascript, html5, html-select

Como ler os valores das opções de um `<select></select>` usando HTML5 + JavaScript?

Ex:

```
<select name="tAtividades" id="cAtividades">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione o Tipo</option>
    <option value="1">Serviços de Saúde</option>
    <option value="2">Alimentos</option>
    <option value="3">Engenharia</option>
    <option value="4">Produtos</option>
</select></p>
```

Como fazer uma função que leia os valores 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 e retorne um valor pra um "Id" *readonly*?

---

Obrigado a todos! Consegui resolver da seguinte forma (Thank You all! I managed to solve as follows):

Problem: Read a "Value" in a "select"

```
<!--Campo de Seleção e Valores atribuídos em cada opção-->
<!--Declarando a função que será executada no JavaScript  onchange="calcAtividades();"  -->
<p><label for="cAtividades">Atividades: </label>
    <select name="tAtividades" id="cAtividades" onchange="calcAtividades();">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione o Tipo</option>
        <option value="1">Serviços de Saúde</option>
        <option value="2">Alimentos</option>
        <option value="3">Engenharia</option>
        <option value="4">Produtos</option>
    </select></p>

<!--Definições onde será mostrado na tela o valor da taxa após a leitura de cada "Atividade" que será selecionada-->
<!--O Id "cTotal" receberá o valor e mostrará na tela no campo de texto que está definida como somente leitura(readonly)-->
<fieldset><legend>Valor da taxa</legend>
    <p><label for="cTotal">Total R$: </label><input type="text" name="tTotal" id="cTotal" placeholder="Total a pagar..." readonly/></p>
</fieldset>

<!--Função JavaScript que fará:
-Leitura do "value" dentro do "select";
-Calculo de qual value é respectivamente relacionada com sua atividade;
-Passar o valor para o Id "cTotal"-->
<script>
    /*####################Função - Calcular Taxa (Atividades)####################*/
    function calcAtividades() {
        //Ler o Select
        var lerSelect = document.getElementById('cAtividades');
        //Ler o value do select
        var taxa = lerSelect.value;
        //Condição de qual value representa tal atividade
        //Se "value" for igual a isso "taxa" vai receber aquilo...
        if (lerSelect.value == 0) {
            taxa = 0;
        }
        if (lerSelect.value == 1) {
            taxa = 100.00;
        }
        else if (lerSelect.value == 2) {
            taxa = 200.00;
        }
        else if (lerSelect.value == 3) {
            taxa = 300.00;
        }
        else if (lerSelect.value == 4) {
            taxa = 400.00;
        }
        //Retornar o valor da taxa para o Id "cTotal"
        document.getElementById('cTotal').value = taxa;
    }
    /*****************************************************************************/
</script>
```

---

Uma outra forma seria assim:

Problem: Read a "Value" in a "select"

```
<!--Campo de Seleção e Valores atribuídos em cada opção-->
<!--Declarando a função que será executada no JavaScript  onchange="calcAtividades();"  -->
<p><label for="cAtividades">Atividades: </label>
    <select name="tAtividades" id="cAtividades" onchange="calcAtividades();">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione o Tipo</option>
        <option value="1">Serviços de Saúde</option>
        <option value="2">Alimentos</option>
        <option value="3">Engenharia</option>
        <option value="4">Produtos</option>

        <!--Este value no caso, será impresso '' (ver função).-->
        <option value="5">Não terá valor</option>
    </select></p>

<!--Definições onde será mostrado na tela o valor da taxa após a leitura de cada "Atividade" que será selecionada-->
<!--O Id "cTotal" receberá o valor e mostrará na tela no campo de texto que está definida como somente leitura(readonly)-->
<fieldset><legend>Valor da taxa</legend>
    <p><label for="cTotal">Total R$: </label><input type="text" name="tTotal" id="cTotal" placeholder="Total a pagar..." readonly/></p>
</fieldset>

<!--Função JavaScript que fará:
-Leitura do "value" dentro do "select";
-Calculo de qual value é respectivamente relacionada com sua atividade;
-Passar o valor para o Id "cTotal"-->
<script>
    /*####################Função - Calcular Taxa (Atividades)####################*/
    function calcAtividades() {
        //Ler o Select
        var selectValue = document.getElementById('cAtividades').value;
        // Valores para cada opçao do select
        var values = {
            0: 200,
            1: 300,
            2: 500,
            3: 700,
            4: 1920
        }
        //Retornar o valor da taxa para o Id "cTotal"
        document.getElementById('cTotal').value = values[selectValue] || '';
        /**
         * values[selectValue] || '' -> Isso faz com que o valor do select seja pego na lista de valores,
         * caso tenha algum valor no objeto values com o valor do select, usamos ele, caso não tenha, usamos
         * uma string vazia para deixar o campo em "branco"
         */
    }
    /*****************************************************************************/
</script>
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt! O que você já tentou fazer em javascript?

Comment: O que queres dizer com "Id" readonly? queres ler os valores quando o select muda, ou ler diretamente do HTML?

Comment: Galera Obrigado pela ajuda!! Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

Comment: Não seria mais fácil você pegar o valor do select e multiplicar por 100 em vez de fazer os `if` ?

Comment: Oi, Jeferson, os valores são apenas exemplos...a questão não é o valor e sim pegar o valor...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
document.getElementById("cAtividades").addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.getElementById("campo").value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<select name="tAtividades" id="cAtividades">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione o Tipo</option>
  <option value="1">Serviços de Saúde</option>
  <option value="2">Alimentos</option>
  <option value="3">Engenharia</option>
  <option value="4">Produtos</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="campo" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Na sua função pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
var atividade = document.getElementById ('cAtividades').value;
```

Então você passa o valor de atividade para onde quer.

Comment: Essa resposta não responde bem a pergunta do OP.